# Are multiple stored procedures necessary here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a table with a structure like

```
create table DrugInteractions
(ndc_fk varchar(50) not null
,ndc_pk varchar(50) not null
,InteractionSeverity int not null,
primary key(ndc_fk,ndc_pk)
)
```

and another with a structure like'

```
   create table DrugList
    (char(11) not null
    ,drug_name varchar(50) not null
    ,drug_class char(3) not null,
    primary key(ndc)
    )
```

There is a 1-many relationship with `drug_class` and drug_name, but of course a 1-1 relationship between drug_name and drug_class.  I currently have three stored procedures which add records to the DrugInteraction table with the following scenarios

All drugs of one class interact with another class

```
CREATE proc spInsertDrugInteractionsByDrugClass          
 @referenceClass char(3)          
,@interactingClass char(3)          
as          
begin          
;with x          
as          
(          
 select distinct  
   drug_name  

 from DrugList          
 where drug_class =@interactingClass          
)          
,y          
as          
(          
 select  drug_name  


 from Druglist          
 where drug_class = @referenceClass          
)          

insert into DrugInteractions(ndc_pk,ndc_fk)          
select distinct            
   upper(x.drug_name)    
  ,upper(y.drug_name)    
 from y,x          
end
```

Sample output from sproc

```
ndc_fk    ncd_pk
drug1     drug2
drug1     drug3
drug1     drug4
```

Another situation is where there is one 'reference' drug class and other drug names entered as parameters to the sproc that that may or may not be the same drug_class

```
CREATE proc spInsertDrugInteractionsByClassAndName        
 @referenceClass char(3)        
,@d1 varchar(50) = null        
,@d2 varchar(50) = null        
,@d3 varchar(50) = null        
,@d4 varchar(50) = null        
,@d5 varchar(50) = null        
as begin        
;with refClassDrugNames       
as        
(        
 select distinct upper(drug_name) as drug_name  
 from DrugList        
 where drug_class = @referenceClass        
),        
drugName    
as        
(        
 select distinct upper(drug_name) as drug_name  
 from DrugList        
 where drug_name in (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5)        
)        
insert into DrugInteractions(ndc_pk,ndc_fk)        
select * from refClassDrugNames,drugName        
end 

Sample output from this sproc would be:
ndc_pk   ndc_fk
drug1    refDrug
drug2    refDrug
drug3    refDrug
drug4    refDrug
```

for situations such as this, is it good/bad design to have multiple stored procedures?  I can't help but think there's got to be a way to make one sproc cover these two scenarios.  Can something akin to this be done in SQL Server only?

Comment: A drug can have more than one drug class.

Comment: if that's a question, it cannot in this particular classification scheme.

Comment: Not a question, just something you might not have been aware of, that can totally ruin you day once the software went live and your system had to handle that :)

Comment: I have ran into a similar problem before and fell flat on my face in a meeting.  This has led to my ardent mistrust of certain data vendors.

Comment: Why are your primary keys char(11)?

Comment: @Dan they shouldn't've been.